# Controlling the PWM output of MCU (STM32L152RE)?

Tags: microcontroller, digital-logic, pwm

Is it, by some means, possible to change the time period of the PWM output of the same microcontroller rather than only its duty cycle? I would like to have a 50 % duty cycle for data logic-0 and a 75 % duty cycle for data logic-1, but the time period for data logic-1 should be twice the data logic-0. The MCU I am planning to use is STM32L152RE, but I am flexible.

Comment: Of course there is. It can be programmed to output almost anything you want. What is the protocol?

Comment: I am planning to use PIE encoding where the time periods for data 0and 1 are different.

Comment: Obviously you can set the period or the PWM would be useless. If doing so in real-time per pulse is sensible or not on the particular PWM hardware peripheral is another story. Worst case scenario is that you'll have "bit-bang" it manually with timers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, most MCUs do allow changing both duty and frequency.

But perhaps it helps to not to think of your signal as frequencies and duties, but simply as high or low pulses with various lengths.